# Nesting a FragmentContainerView inside a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment representing a sort of custom numerical keypad, and now I'd like to put this inside of a dialog popup. So I have a layout like this (`dialog_numpad.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainerView"
        android:name="com.github.me.myapp.NumpadFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and then I have a dialog class like this:

```
public class NumpadPopupFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater inflater = requireActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_numpad, null);
        builder
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("Start", null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to instantiate this thing with

```
NumpadPopupFragment dialog = new NumpadPopupFragment();
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "new");
```

from within an Activity, I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.github.me.myapp PID: 21457
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6 in com.github.me.myapp:layout/dialog_numpad: Binary XML file line #6 in com.github.me.myapp:layout/dialog_numpad: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6 in com.github.me.myapp:layout/dialog_numpad: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
```

It seems like I'm not allowed to nest fragments, maybe? But looking it up online, it seems you can nest fragments since about 2011, in Android. Is there a way to get the behavior I want? For architectural reasons, I don't really want to just fold the inner numpad fragment into the dialog fragment, I'd like for it to be reusable outside of just that popup.

Comment: What version of Fragments are you using? You should be getting a lint warning for using the wrong LayoutInflater in `requireActivity().getLayoutInflater()` instead of the layout inflater of the `DialogFragment` itself (i.e., just `getLayoutInflater()`).

Comment: @ianhanniballake Getting rid of the `requireActivity()` seems to have done it, thanks. I'm still having other problems, but I think they're unrelated.

Comment: So are you getting a Lint warning about that call? Are you using the latest version of Fragments?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Definitely no linter warning. I'm not sure what version of Fragments I'm using. I'm on appcompat 1.5.0.